# Visual C# Timer Not Ticking

Tags: c#

There is a little code for basic Windows Form Application I wrote. But something goes wrong. I'm starting the app, everything is OK but if i start the timer, its running for first time and doesn't repeating. What should i do?

Sorry for grammar mistakes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Zamanlayıcı
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public int saat;
    public int dakika;
    public int saniye;
    public int zaman;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void baslat_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void durdur_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void demizle_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saat_box.Clear();
        dakika_box.Clear();
        saniye_box.Clear();
        zaman_text.Text = "00:00:00";

    }

    private void ses_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int saat = int.Parse(saat_box.Text);
        int dakika = int.Parse(dakika_box.Text);
        int saniye = int.Parse(saniye_box.Text);
        int zaman = saat * 60 * 60 + dakika * 60 + saniye;

        int saat2 = zaman / 60 / 60;
        int dakika2 = zaman / 60 % 60;
        int saniye2 = zaman % 60;

        if(zaman > 0) {
        zaman--;
        zaman_text.Text = saat2.ToString("00") + ":" + dakika2.ToString("00") + ":" + saniye2.ToString("00");
        }if(zaman == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Zaman doldu!", "Bitti", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure the tick event is bound to timer1_Tick_1

Comment: When i press the start button its setting the text, but doesn't repeating so im sure it is bound to correct event

Comment: What is the text at that point.. have you put a breakpoint in the tick event?

Comment: Comment out timer1.Stop() in durdur_button_Click() to make sure thats not getting triggered as well..

Comment: Insert "timer1.enabled=false" at the beginning of the "timer1_Tick_1" procedure and ""timer1.enabled=true" at the end. However, these missing instructions don't explain your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the timer runs and `timer1_Tick_1` gets called every second. The problem is that you have a local variable `zaman` in the `timer1_Tick_1`, which always gets the same value `saat * 60 * 60 + dakika * 60 + saniye;`, so you always see that initial value. Remove the local variable and use only the field `zaman` instead; make its initial calculation when the timer starts:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

        public int saat;
        public int dakika;
        public int saniye;
        public int zaman;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void baslat_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            int saat = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int dakika = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int saniye = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            zaman = saat * 60 * 60 + dakika * 60 + saniye;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void durdur_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void demizle_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Text = "00:00:00";

        }

        private void ses_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {


            int saat2 = zaman / 60 / 60;
            int dakika2 = zaman / 60 % 60;
            int saniye2 = zaman % 60;

            if (zaman > 0) {
                zaman--;
                textBox4.Text = saat2.ToString("00") + ":" + dakika2.ToString("00") + ":" + saniye2.ToString("00");
            }
            if (zaman == 0) {
                MessageBox.Show("Zaman doldu!", "Bitti", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sometimes we can miss something that important :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Alex said, you declare `zaman` inside the tick event handler, so every time it ticks (every second), it just resets the value.  You should be declaring your variables outside of the tick event handler, and modifying them within.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public int saat;
    public int dakika;
    public int saniye;
    public int zaman;

    public Form1() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void baslat_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        int saat = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int dakika = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int saniye = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        zaman = saat * 3600 + dakika * 60 + saniye;      //You were multiplying by 60 2x - just multiply by 3600

        timer1.Start();     
    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int saat2 = zaman / 3600;   //You were dividing by 60 2x - just divide by 3600
        int dakika2 = zaman / 60 % 60;
        int saniye2 = zaman % 60;

        if (zaman > 0) 
        {
            zaman--;
            textBox4.Text = saat2.ToString("00") + ":" + dakika2.ToString("00") + ":" + saniye2.ToString("00");
        }
        if (zaman == 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("Zaman doldu!", "Bitti", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

}
```